# Как переключаться между ветками в git, когда в текущей ветке есть несохраненные изменения?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash

Есть у меня проект. Находится в папке `project`. Инициализирую Git, создаю новую ветку:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'
git branch feature
// делаю что-то для feature
```

Что имею? Две ветки. Одна — `master`. Другая — `feature.` Они отличаются.
Я изменил некоторые файлы в папке `project` (пока работал в ветке `feature`). Но тут мне очень понадобилось взглянуть на файлы, которые в `master`.

Как сделать так, чтобы в папке `project` находились не те файлы, над которыми я сейчас работаю `feature`, а те, что были в ветке `master`?

Comment: [RTFM](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git)

Comment: как вариант - спрятать изменения "git stash", перейти на другую ветку, взглянуть на то, что было нужно, перейти обратно и вытащить изменения обратно "git stash pop"

Answer (score 34):

Если у вас уже есть ветка `feature`, то после коммита в нее сделайте `git checkout master` – это переключит текущую ветку на `master`.

Пока вы не вкоммитили изменения, вы не можете переключиться на другую ветку. Выхода два: вкоммитить изменения или отложить их. Второе можно сделать с помощью `git stash` – это добавит текущие незакоммиченные изменения в стек изменений и сбросит текущую рабочую копию до `HEAD`'а репозитория. Далее вы сможете:

- `git stash list`: показать все изменения в стеке
- `git stash show`: показать последнее изменение в стеке (патч)
- `git stash apply`: применить последнее изменение из стека к текущей рабочей копии
- `git stash drop`: удалить последнее изменение в стеке
- `git stash pop`: применить последнее изменение из стека к текущей рабочей копии и удалить его из стека
- `git stash clear`: очистить стек изменений

Comment: Также вместо stash можно использовать обычный commit (а потом откатить его) - это позволит "привязать" сохраненные изменения к ветке. Еще есть такой механизм как worktree для самых тяжелых случаев.