# Можно ли оставить изменения в ветке, не закоммичивая их?

Tags: git, git-stash

Порой в процессе работы мне нужно переключатся на другую ветку (например, чтобы пофиксить баг), соответственно, когда я переключаюсь на другую ветку, все незакомиченные изменения тянутся в эту ветку и мешают работать.

Можно ли это как-то изменить, чтобы незакоммиченые изменения оставались в предыдущей ветке?

Comment: `git stash` для откладывания "в ящик", либо коммит а потом к финалу задачи `squash` чтобы объеденить коммиты

Comment: возможный дубликат: [Как переключаться между ветками в git, когда в текущей ветке есть несохраненные изменения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/153502/178576)

Comment: `git worktree --help`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

можно «спрятать» (stash) внесённые изменения с помощью одноимённой команды. у неё есть много под-команд (см. [`man git-stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)).

1. прячем изменения (если не указана под-команда, то подразумевается `save`):

   ```
   $ git stash
   Saved working directory and index state WIP on ветка: хэш описание коммита
   HEAD is now at хэш описание коммита
   ```
2. смотрим спрятанное под-командой `list`:

   ```
   $ git stash list
   stash@{0}: WIP on ветка: хэш описание коммита
   ```
3. извлекаем спрятанное под-командой `pop`:

   ```
   $ git stash pop
   On branch ветка
   Changes not staged for commit:
     (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
     (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

           modified:   файл

   no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
   Dropped refs/stash@{0} (3acbab1c34d0559dcb264fe443471a7ff20aa319)
   ```

   последняя строчка извещает, что «спрятанное» удалено из «кладовки». можно и не удалять, заменив под-команду `pop` под-командой `apply`.

---

подробнее:

- [Инструменты Git - Прятанье](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5)
- [Волшебство Git — Чудеса ветвления — Временные Ветки](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch04.html#_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: `git worktree` — наше всё. `stash` многим неудобен (не людям, а причинами), но хорош для одного, двух изменений. Если во временном хранилище больше десятка комитов с самых разнообразных веток, то ой.