# Как решить конфликт после удаленных изменений git?

Tags: git

Объясните как нужно поступать в следующей ситуации. Начал работать вдвоем с другим человеком, используя git. Предположим, изначально у нас были синхронизованы репозитории на `master/HEAD`. Я сделал какие-то изменения, например в файле `some.cpp`. За это время мой партнер тоже сделал изменения в том же файле и успел сделать `commit` и `push`. Какие мои дальнейшие действия, чтобы записать мои изменения и сохранить его?

Перед  коммитом, как я понял, нужно сделать пулл, но при этом вылезает ошибка:

```
igormahov@IMPC:~/git/test$ git pull
remote: Перечисление объектов: 5, готово.
remote: Подсчет объектов: 100% (5/5), готово.
remote: Сжатие объектов: 100% (3/3), готово.
remote: Всего 3 (изменения 1), повторно использовано 0 (изменения 0)
Распаковка объектов: 100% (3/3), готово.
Из igormahov.ru:test
   f4b3c9a..8172316  master     -> origin/master
Обновление f4b3c9a..8172316
error: Ваши локальные изменения в указанных файлах будут перезаписаны при слиянии:
        README.md
Сделайте коммит или спрячьте ваши изменения перед слиянием веток.
Прерываю
```

Comment: *сохраните его* — кого именно вы хотите сохранить?. ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я имел ввиду его (другого человека) изменения

Comment: так что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Я так понял, что перед тем как делать коммит, нужно сделать пулл, но он выдает ошибку

Comment: Если я просто сделаю коммит, то потру изменения партнера

Comment: какую именно ошибку? (вы, вроде, не новичок, уже 12 вопросов задали, и вот на 13-м вам надо заново рассказывать, как правильно задавать вопросы).

Comment: см изменения в вопросе

Comment: Ваш коммит не затрет изменения, сделанные другим человеком. Но потом при пуше возникнет конфликт, который придется решать ручками.

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо. А на продакшене также постоянно делают?

Comment: Нет. На продакшене обычно не пушат разные люди в один файл в одной ветке.

Comment: программа вам и подсказывает: «сделайте коммит или [спрячьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677335/178576) ваши изменения».